# Apply function to loop item

Tags: python, loops, iteration

Consider the code below:

```
f = open('file.txt')

for l in f:
    k = l.strip() # Remove the newline character.
    print(k)

f.close()
```

I'd like to automatically remove the newline. I know I could do:

```
for k in [l.strip() for l in f]:
    print(k)
```

But this requires looping the length of `f` twice (and loading the whole thing into memory). I'm wondering if there is something even more Pythonic like:

```
for lambda l: l.strip() in f:
    print(l)
```

or maybe just:

```
for l.strip() in f:
    print(l)
```

Of course, neither of these work. To see how this could be applied elsewhere, here's an example with nested lists:

```
d =  [['hi'], ['hello'], ['howdy']]
for item in d:
    item = item[0] # Get the nested item.
    if item == 'hello':
         print(item)
```

Comment: The second way seems enoughly pythonic to me

Comment: What do you mean "automatically" remove the newline?  Your first example is fine.  Just do what you need to do inside the loop.

Comment: Wow, thanks for all the quick responses. Python always has a fantastic way to get what you want. Both YatharthROCK's and iCodez's answers are great. Since @YatharthROCK came with a few references, I accepted it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Welcome to the world of Python iterators :)

You have the right idea with the list comprehensions, except you want it to lazy-load and not build up the entire list in memory first (which may even be untenable for very large files): use **generator expressions** instead, which have the same syntax except the square brackets are replaced by parentheses (which you can omit if it is the sole argument to a function):

```
with open(filename) as f:
    for l in (l.strip() for l in f.readlines()):
        print(l)
```

> **Source:** Read more about them in [the relevant Python Enhancement Proposal](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0289/) and the [official docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#grammar-token-generator_expression).

---

An alternative, functional way of doing it with a syntax similar to LISP's is using `map` which applies a function to each element of an iterator — it doesn't have to be a sequence, and assuming you're on Python this will involve looping through all the lines just once:

```
for l in map(lambda l: l.strip (), f):
    print(l)
```

---

Also, `f.readlines()` would probably be clearer than just looping over `f`, and a `with` statement is more Pythonic than calling `f.close()` yourself.

Comment: The `map` solution can be simplified to `map(str.strip, f)`

Comment: Also using `readlines()` in the first solution kinda misses the whole point of not having to read the file to memory and even of using a generator. `readlines()` returns a list of all the lines, but files are already iterators themselves, lazily yielding their lines. So it should be `for l in (l.strip() for l in f):`

Answer (score 7):

You can use a [generator expression](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#grammar-token-generator_expression):

```
for k in (l.strip() for l in f):
    print(k)
```

This is very similar to the list comprehension, except that it produces items lazily (one-by-one) instead of collecting them all into a list at once.  So, we only loop the length of `f` a single time and also avoid dumping everything into memory all at one time.

Comment: Do you know whether this has been back-ported to 2?

Comment: Yes, generator expressions have been around since version 2.4.  See here for details: https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/2.4.html#pep-289-generator-expressions

Comment: Oh cool, I thought they were a Python 3 only thing with all the other lazy-loading aspects of map, sorted and the rest. You've been using it for much longer than I have ;)

Answer (score 0):

Haven't tested but should be right: the important part is using `replace`. In my opinion a for loop is a valid way to do it, but if you want a one liner, use something like:

```
no_new_lines = None
with open('path/to/file', 'rb') as file_content:
    no_new_lines = file_content.read().replace('\r\n', '\n').replace('\n', '')
```

Please do note that "`replace`" makes a copy of the to-be-replaced content. A huge file opened on a system with little memory will cause issues (`MemoryError`). Anyway, test it, see what works better.